# Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" while adding subview to main view

Tags: iphone

i am adding two labels and two image view to subview.

when ever i tap on the button i add this subview to mainview.

I am getting images from the web server and save it in local simulator documents.

```
NSMutableString *about_name_str = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [about_name_str appendString:[myDictionary objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
    [about_name_str appendString:@" "];
    [about_name_str appendString:[myDictionary objectForKey:@"lastname"]];
    [about_name_label setText:about_name_str]; 
    NSMutableString *about_addr_str = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [about_addr_str appendString:[myDictionary objectForKey:@"state"]];
    [about_addr_str appendString:@","];
    [about_addr_str appendString:[myDictionary objectForKey:@"country"]];
    [about_addr_label setText:about_addr_str];
    about_image.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagepath];
    about_logo.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:logopath];
    if ([myDictionary objectForKey:@"companyurl"]) {
        [about_url_button setTitle:[myDictionary objectForKey:@"companyurl"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        about_url_button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else {
        about_url_button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }




        [self.view addSubview:about_view];
```

this my code.

some times i got `Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".` and application quits.

i check by placing break points,and in debugger i did n't get where i am getting error.

can any one please help me,How can i resolve this.

Thank u in  advance.

Comment: Do you know where the code crashs?

Comment: 1. You should use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[myDictionary objectForKey:@"firstname"],[myDictionary objectForKey@"secondname"]];`. It will be more efficient and more pleasant to read back. 2. NEVER put _s into variable names! Its horrible. In objectivec variable names are camel coded eg instead of `about_url_button` you should use `aboutUrlButton`.

Comment: 3. Can we see where you're creating about_view? Try setting NSZombieEnabled to YES in your app execution arguments and see if you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use NSZombie.. It is a easy way to find where the EXCBADACCESS occurs... 
It will specify which Method where and Which object gets deallocated(Its pretty awesome concept i like in Instruments)...

See this Link
http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Answer (score -1):

You should insert a breakpoint before this code is executed then step through it to find the exact line which is causing the bad access. You probably have a null or wild pointer somewhere.

Comment: He wrote: "i check by placing break points,and in debugger i did n't get where i am getting error."